# Compressing data into gzip using zlib

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
conn.request("POST", "someurl", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    #print(data)
    d = zlib.compressobj(wbits=zlib.MAX_WBITS|16)
    data = d.compress(data)
    #print(data)
```

In the above code I receive data from an API and convert it to GZIP using the zlib python library. After converting the data, I upload the data using another API. The problem I am seeing here is that the data does get compressed but it's not in the gzip format.

Is it possible to gzip compress data using zlib library. P.S: I cannot use gzip library to compress data.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use gzip?

Comment: "The compress and deflate functions produce data in the zlib format, which is different and incompatible with the gzip format. The gz* functions in zlib on the other hand use the gzip format. Both the zlib and gzip formats use the same compressed data format internally, but have different headers and trailers around the compressed data." https://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq18 so no you can't

Comment: @Dan-Dev Interesting, Zlib allows me to decompress gzipped compressed data but doesn't allow for gzip compression. Thank you.

Comment: @Brian Can only write code with limited python modules, gzip isn't one that is available to me.